# Enter last non-NULL value in column and put into new column for every entry SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, syntax, sql-order-by

I'm trying to follow a tutorial completed by SQLMag
http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/last-non-null-puzzle

```
SELECT id, col1, relevantid,
                            MAX(relevantid) OVER( ORDER BY id
                                                  ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ) AS grp
                          FROM dbo.T1
                            CROSS APPLY ( VALUES( CASE WHEN col1 IS NOT NULL THEN id END ) )
                              AS A(relevantid);
```

to get this to work on sql server 2008. Everytime i try to MAX(relevantid) OVER (ORDER BY id) I receive a syntax error near order . Is there a way around this if I partition it is not a problem but if I only include order I get problems.

Comment: What is the exact error?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like some of your syntax will not work with SQL server 2008 after reading the Microsoft doc and finding this article from brent Ozar.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql
https://www.brentozar.com/sql-syntax-examples/window-function-examples-sql-server/

it would be better to use a later version of sql server for your own use if thats what you are trying to do.